# apt installs different version of R than requested

Tags: r, docker, ubuntu

### Summary

I am currently building a docker image with RStudio that is based on a previous version of R. When I installed R libraries in that image and tried to access those libraries with another, prebuilt docker image I received the following message:

```
library("dplyr")
```

> Warning message:
> package ´dplyr´ was built under R version 4.1.2

For some reason the R version I get and the R version I install are not the same. Is there some way to inspect the packages on https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/focal-cran40/? What is the reason for the discrepancy between my requested R version of 4.0.4 and the installed version of 4.1.2?

### What I have tried

In my dockerfile I explicitly define my target version of 4.0.4.
`RUN apt-get install -y r-base=4.0.4-1.2004.0 r-recommended=4.0.4-1.2004.0`

When I verify my R Version it does show 4.1.2:
`Rscript -e 'R.Version()$version.string'`

> [1] "R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)"

When I verify my R installation it shows that 4.0.4 is installed:
`apt policy r-base`

```
 r-base:  
  Installed: 4.0.4-1.2004.0  
  Candidate: 4.1.2-1.2004.0  
  Version table:  
     4.1.2-1.2004.0 500  
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages  
     4.1.1-1.2004.0 500  
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages  
     4.1.0-1.2004.0 500  
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages  
     4.0.5-1.2004.0 500  
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages  
 *** 4.0.4-1.2004.0 500  
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages  
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status  
     4.0.3-1.2004.0 500  
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages  
     4.0.2-1.2004.0 500  
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages  
     4.0.1-1.2004.0 500  
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages  
     4.0.0-1.2004.0 500  
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages  
     3.6.3-2 500  
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

### Steps to reproduce:

I start with a clean Ubuntu 20.04 image.
`docker run -it --entrypoint bash ubuntu:focal`

I make sure I am current and then add some packages.

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common dirmngr gdebi-core curl
```

tzdata wants some info during the installation (this can be anything I suspect):

```
1
1
```

Add the signing key for the r-project repos and add the repo. `$(lsb_release -cs)` resolves to "focal".

```
curl https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc  
add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"
```

Check the available **r-base** package versions:
`apt policy r-base`

```
r-base:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.1.3-1.2004.0
  Version table:
     4.1.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.5-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.4-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     3.6.3-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

Install R:
`apt-get install -y r-base=4.0.4-1.2004.0 r-recommended=4.0.4-1.2004.0`

Check the installed Version:
`Rscript -e 'R.Version()$version.string'`

> [1] "R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)"

What am I missing? Is it possible that there might be some issue with the r-rpoject repo?

Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  But I am sorry: can you shorten this and maybe focus on your key question?  If you do _not_ want 4.1.3, why do you add the repos adding it?  Also, which container and version did you start from?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I am sorry but I am not sure how to shorten this without losing relevant information. I have added a question that should clarify that I don't know why there is a discrepancy between my requested version of 4.0.4 and installed version 4.1.x

I am not sure about your comment that I "add the repos adding it if I don't want it". I add the r-project repo to be able to access 4.0.4. The standard Repo only provides R Version 3.6.3, which you can verify by following the MRE steps and excluding the r-project repo.

Comment: Sure. See my answer. I actually build and provde a ton of different Rocker containers for just this _but all those generally use the most recent R version as that is what we all are after_.  If you want R 4.0.4, maybe try `docker pull r-base:4.0.4` (though that one is Debian-based).

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible since I need to use a Cloudera-provided base image.

Comment: See the edited answer.  This comment was for illustration.  Also, earlier you said `ubuntu:focal`.  What does Cloudera have to do with that?

Comment: Cloudera has nothing to do with the official ubuntu:focal image. But the point of a minimal reproducible example is to make it as light as possible and illustrate the question. Which it does... You sure like to shot your answers from your hip.

Comment: I have provided hundreds of hours of volunteer work around this, 20+ years on the Debian R packages alone, maybe a decade+ helping Michael with the PPAs as well as several years for the Rocker containers.  I really don;t have to help you if you would rather be snippy at me.  I found your initial question incomprehensible, but we eventually seem to have worked out where your misunderstanding let you astray.  But if you prefer to show me attitude, have at it.  At least I also don't know who you are as hide behind an anon handle.  "Stay classy, San Diego!"

Comment: As I don't have enough rep to open a private chat: I am thankful to anyone who contributes time, energy, and motivation into OS projects, this also includes you even though I don't exactly know who you or Michael are. 
Still, I also appreciate a focused answer if a focused question is stipulated or at least pointers of what was not understood. If you don't have the time to look at a question maybe don't try to force the question into your perfect format so you can glance over it and instantly know the answer. When I help someone focus on quality and not quantity so they are not afraid to ask.

Comment: Michael is Michael Rutter, whose PPA you use in your question.

Comment: In this case, I will carry a piece of Michael in my systems from this day onward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel) the issue lies with how I tried to install the packages.

`r-base` and `r-recommended` are meta-packages that contain further packages. Meta packages can be requested by version but do not propagate the requested version down to their child packages.
This means if you want to install a specific version of `R` the binary is included in `r-base-core`. The same goes for `r-recommended` and the recommended `R` `base` packages which can be installed via apt into /usr/lib/R/library.

To install the specific version of R that is needed the following can be written to the `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG R_INSTALL_VERSION="4.0.4-1.2004.0"
RUN apt-get install -y  \
  r-base-core=${R_INSTALL_VERSION} \
  r-base-html=${R_INSTALL_VERSION} \
  r-doc-html=${R_INSTALL_VERSION} \
  r-base-dev=${R_INSTALL_VERSION}
```

Note that `r-recommended` was excluded here since 11 out of 15 `base` packages had dependency issues as described above.
If those packages are needed one can list the available versions of a package via `apt policy <package-name>` and pick a version that is compatible with the requested `R` version.
This package version does not correspond to the `R` Version:

```
ARG R_INSTALL_VERSION="4.0.4-1.2004.0"
RUN apt-get install -y  \
  r-base-core=${R_INSTALL_VERSION} \
  r-base-html=${R_INSTALL_VERSION} \
  r-doc-html=${R_INSTALL_VERSION} \
  r-base-dev=${R_INSTALL_VERSION} \
  r-cran-cluster=2.1.1-1.2004.0 \
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, this seems confused.

You open up with "binary from the PPA are built under a more current version": yes, and that is a feature.  If you do *not* want a current `dplyr` (via a current `r-cran-dplyr`) then do not add the PPA by Michael (which you do correctly by following the steps [at the README](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/).

The disconnect, if there is one, is that you seem to think that you point to that PPA and somehow get versions matching an arbitrarily picked R version, here your 4.0.4.  You cannot, and we never say you can.

What we provide via the CRAN mirror of the other Rutter PPA are

- current versions of R for the various operating systems, i.e. Michael [tweeted just yesterday](https://twitter.com/marutterstat/status/1503530090734444552) that 4.0.3 is now available off my Debian binaries
- about 5000 additional binaries off CRAN for the LTS release but also generally built with most current R version---which is why the `dplyr` binary signalled it was built recently under 4.0.4

So in short this is not a time machine mechanism.

(For that you can look into the RSPM builds for which I have a container `rocker/r-rspm:20.04` to use RSPM, you could try the date-indexing support they offer. I don't use enable that by default.)

If I misunderstood anything, please add a comment and maybe clarify above.  The r-sig-debian list is also available for more follow-up.

*Edit:*  Per the discussion in the comments, we now know better.  OP constrained *just one* package from the set and expected that `apt` would magically expand.  That is not how it happens. Based on some other `Dockerfile` I wrote, I recommend something along the lines of

```
    && apt-get install -t unstable -y --no-install-recommends \
            # ... some omitted ...
            r-base=${R_BASE_VERSION}-* \
            r-base-dev=${R_BASE_VERSION}-* \
            r-recommended=${R_BASE_VERSION}-* \
            # ... more lines omitted ...
```

which is how I impose versions when I build the `r-base` container. The versioned `r-base-dev` will pull in the versioned `r-base-core` container, you could also list it explicitly.

Comment: I am sorry but there has been a confusion about the question...

Comment: I am sorry but there has been a confusion about the question...
My question is about the discrepancy between the R Version that I want to install via apt and has nothing to do with CRAN binaries. 
As I have defined in the question I install (and build, this was not included in the question) packages via the docker image I want to build. 
After that I want to use those packages from another Image. This has showed me that R installed via ```apt-get install -y r-base=4.0.4-1.2004.0``` installs R 4.1.3
The libraries are a symptom to the problem described in the first two sentences.

Comment: Look at `dpkg -l | grep r-`.  `r-base` is just a meta-package.  You want `r-base-core` as it provides the `R` binary.  Your constraint on `r-base` does NOT carry over to `r-base-core`.  That simple.  Please see the edited question -- that should help you.